# Why can't I use an integer as a key using the new Ruby 1.9.2 hash syntax?

Tags: ruby, hash

The new hash syntax in Ruby 1.9.2 means that I can do the following:

```
my_hash = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

... which is equivalent to:

```
my_hash = {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3}
```

Okay, so using the old syntax it's possible to do this (first key is an integer):

```
my_hash = {1 => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3}
```

And I've found it's even possible to mix the new and the old syntax like this:

```
my_hash = {1 => 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

So, if we invoke the 'principle of least surprise', one would expect that the following would be legal:

```
my_hash = {1: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

... but it isn't. It generates a syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: (irb):40: syntax error, unexpected '='
my_hash =  = {1: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

Can anybody explain if this is this a limitation of the parser, or are there very good reasons why this isn't possible, or allowed?

Comment: Since `a: 1` is equivalent to `:a => 1` and not `a => 1`, the POLS dictates that `1: 1` should be equivalent to `:1 => 1` and it is - both cause a syntax error.

Comment: Yes... I see it now; Of course! Ironically, that's the only experiment I didn't try. I guess my own headstrong preconceptions got in the way of the POLS! Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This syntax is only for Ruby 'symbols', and is an alternative to the common usage:

```
:symbol => 5
```

rather than as a general key. [More on symbols here.](http://www.oreillynet.com/ruby/blog/2005/12/digging_into_ruby_symbols_1.html) And others have written about this with respect to the principal of least surprise (see [here](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/symbols.htm)).

Comment: Ahhh... that makes total sense. I didn't realise the new syntax was only for symbols. Thank you for your supernaturally quick response.