# Why is "300".intern valid but :300 is not

Tags: ruby, hash, symbols

I am learning Ruby using codeacadamy.com and the current assignment is to create a hash with a list of movies. So, being me, the first movie I put in was 300.

```
movies = {
  300: 3,
  titanic: 1,
  joe_versus_the_volcanoe: 3
}
```

and I noticed that 300 threw an error:

```
(ruby):1: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting tASSOC
    300: 3,
        ^
```

This made a lot of sense, but then I tried using a string.

```
puts "300".intern
puts "300".to_sym
puts :300
```

The first two are valid symbols and output 300 to the screen, but the last one throws an error. I understand that 300 should error, because it doesn't start with a valid method character (a-zA-Z_ as far as I know) but then what are `.to_sym` and `.intern` doing to make `"300"` a valid symbol?

Comment: Possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281397/why-cant-i-use-an-integer-as-a-key-using-the-new-ruby-1-9-2-hash-syntax

Comment: Not quite, I understand what his problem was and actually played around doing almost that exact thing, but I still don't know why it will let "300".to_sym be a symbol since symbols should start with valid method characters.

Comment: Read the  first 2 lines from here -http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Symbol.html

Comment: But '"300": 3' doesn't work either. But that might just be because the 'symbol:' syntax isn't as fleshed out as '=>', because ':"300" => 3' works just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbol you create by saying `puts "300".to_sym` isn't creating the symbol with a Fixnum, it's creating it with a string. You seem to be mixing up Fixnum's versus strings here.

`:"300"` is a valid symbol

`:300` is not

When you type `puts "300".to_sym`, it returns `:"300"`

```
1.9.3-p484 :002 > "300".to_sym
 => :"300"
```

You could just as easily make your hash

```
1.9.3-p484 :013 > hsh = {
1.9.3-p484 :014 >     :"300" => 3,
1.9.3-p484 :015 >     :something_else => 2
1.9.3-p484 :016?>   }
 => {:"300"=>3, :something_else=>2} 
1.9.3-p484 :017 > hsh[:"300"]
 => 3
```

and that would work fine.

Your problem would be more accurately stated if you tried to send `to_sym` to a `Fixnum`.

```
1.9.3-p484 :018 > 300.to_sym
    NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for 300:Fixnum
    from (irb):18
    from /Users/rsahae/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/irb:18:in `<main>'
```

Comment: In general, symbols follow variable/method name rules i.e. the first character cannot be a number. Unless you use quotes, then anything goes.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an answer to that, and I was wondering that as well. My guess is it's just something with the interpreter and how it handles that specific syntax shortcut.

Comment: I think this answer misrepresents the problem somewhat. The problem is not that `Fixnum` doesn't respond to `to_sym`, but that `:300` is not valid syntax for a symbol literal: http://pastebin.com/aFNua2rL

Comment: I think the OP acknowledges in the post that they understand that :300 isn't valid. The end of the post reads **"I understand that 300 should error, because it doesn't start with a valid method character (a-zA-Z_ as far as I know) but then what are .to_sym and .intern doing to make "300" a valid symbol?"**

In that case, I believe the answer addresses the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can put pretty much any character you want in a symbol, just not with the `:name` syntax for symbol literals.

```
"1 whole sentence with all sorts of characters!".to_sym
#=> :"1 whole sentence with all sorts of characters!"
```

One alternative symbol literal syntax you could use for this is the `:"string"` syntax:

```
movies = {
  :"300" => 3,
  :titanic => 1,
  :joe_versus_the_volcanoe => 3
}
#=> {:"300"=>3, :titanic=>1, :joe_versus_the_volcanoe=>3}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
puts :300
```

Does not fail because it doesn't start with a valid method character, it fails because 300 is not a string. `puts :"300"` does work.

Comment: But `puts :a300` works, and `a300` on its own is not a string in Ruby either.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Good point. The error message is: `syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END`, so the correct answer is probably explaining what that means exactly- which I don't know.

Comment: It means that `300` is not a valid identifier in Ruby: http://web.njit.edu/all_topics/Prog_Lang_Docs/html/ruby/syntax.html#ident