# In the future, can I use the new hash syntax with array as key?

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I'm creating a hash with an array as key, e.g.:

```
versions = { [1, 2, 3] => 'some-code-name' }
```

I would like to do the same but using the new hash syntax, which raises an error as of now:

```
versions = { [1, 2, 3] : 'some-code-name' }
# => SyntaxError: (irb):18: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting =>
```

I would like to know if they will implement it in the future (just because it is syntactic sugar).

There's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281397/why-cant-i-use-an-integer-as-a-key-using-the-new-ruby-1-9-2-hash-syntax) explaining that:

> This syntax is only for Ruby 'symbols', and is an alternative to the common usage:
>
> ```
> :symbol => 5
> ```
>
> rather than as a general key. More on symbols here. And others have written about this with respect to the principal of least surprise (see here).

But I have been able to do the same with a `string` and thought that maybe they would extend this functionality to be globally available within hashes.

Comment: I wouldn't really consider the ability to use `:` instead of `=>` to be "syntactic sugar".

Comment: What do you mean that you "have been able to do the same with `String`"? That cannot be true. In other words, what this question claims cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @sawa, just a typo. Meant to say 'a string' not the String object, guessing you were just fishing for a downvote tho :)

Comment: Still. No version of Ruby ever released, currently in development, or planned supports string keys with the JSON-style hash syntax. Originally, it supported solely symbols that are also valid identifiers (more precisely, valid labels). Recently, it was augmented to supporting quoting for symbols which aren't valid Ruby identifiers. I don't know what language you are talking about when you say you "have been able to do the same with a `string`", but it sure wasn't Ruby. Maybe you could give an example of what you are talking about. My guess is that you are using some kind of preprocessor.

Comment: Well @JörgWMittag All I can say is that typing `h = { 'between quotes': 1 }` actually results to `{ :'between quotes' => 1 }` which just looks weird to me anyways. But I just realized that typing `h.keys.first.class` evaluates to `Symbol` So yeah idk why I didn't even think of that yesterday :< So to my understanding now is that the new-hash syntax s actually the new-hash-symbol syntax, right?

Comment: `:'between quotes'` is just normal `Symbol` literal syntax for symbols that aren't valid Ruby identifiers. It has been supported for ages. The colon/JSON-style hash syntax was always intended solely for symbol keys. It was introduced mainly as an intermediate step towards keyword arguments. Note that ECMAScript object literals, upon which the syntax is based, also only support strings (ECMASCript doesn't have symbols) which are valid ECMAScript identifiers as unquoted keys, not numbers or arrays or anything else.

Comment: Yeah I'm quite new in this world @JörgWMittag but thanks for the very clear explanation on this - much appriciated! My question got answered yesterday but my (after)thought got confirmed today, have a good one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I have been able to do the same with a `string` ...

I think you are referring to the `"name": value` syntax.

Let's see:

```
{"foo": 123} #=> {:foo=>123}
```

Notice what happens to the "string"? It becomes a symbol.

Within a hash literal `"foo": value` is a shortcut for `:"foo" => value` and `:"foo"` is in fact a symbol:

```
:"foo" #=> :foo
```

> I would like to know if they will implement it in the future (just because syntactic sugar)?

Who knows? But I don't think so.

Comment: Sorry for the last comment there, checking on phone and missed the last bit :< Thanks!